# NoMethodError - undefined method error - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'd like to return a random webpage that I can display as a link in a view but I can't get the method to work properly:

Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `randomize_webpages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Webpage:0x00000101d84e68>
```

Webpage Model

```
 def randomize_webpages
    shuffle.first
 end
```

WebpagesController

```
def index
  @webpages = Webpage.all
end
```

CSV seeder for Webpage

```
link
http://www.buzzfeed.com
http://www.reddit.com
http://boston.com
http://phys.org
http://www.popsci.com
http://www.technologyreview.com
http://techcrunch.com
```

View Index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Take Me Anywhere But Here', @random_page %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the method as a class method of the model

```
class Webpage
  def self.randomize_webpages
    shuffle.first
  end
end
```

instead of

```
class Webpage
  def randomize_webpages
    shuffle.first
  end
end
```

Please note that the method is very inefficient. You are loading all the records and then selecting one. There are more efficient ways.

One possible improvement is to select only the ID, then query for that ID. Another alternative is to delegate to the underlying driver, assuming it supports the query.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you calling `randomize_webpages` on `@webpages`, are you? This is a collection, so you have to do something like `@webpages.first.randomize_webpages` or iterate over them (you didn't include relevant code so I can't tell what you want to do) to get this working.

Comment: I want the link to change every time the page is reloaded and be a new random link. Fixed the method but am now getting a circular dependency error?

Comment: Fixed the error, was a problem with a helper - no longer an issue. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a class method, then you could use `sample`:

```
def self.randomize_webpages
  all.sample
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class method to your model

```
class WebPage < ActiveRecord::Base     
  def self.random
    order('RAND()').first
  end
  ....
end
```

Then you can call it from as `WebPage.random` in your controller, save to an instance variable, and use that instance variable in your view.

Please: note that 'RAND()' is MySQL specific. If you do not use MySql, search for the correct syntax (if any)

Comment: In this way, you do not fetch all webpages from database first